# Filtering inside the dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I want to extract two first symbols in case three first symbols match a certain pattern (first two symbols should be any of those inside the brackets [ptkbdgG_fvsSxzZhmnNJlrwj], the third symbol should be any of those inside the brackets[IEAOYye|aouKLM@)3*<!(#0~q^LMOEK].

The first two lines work correctly.
The last lines do not work and I do not understand why. The code doesn`t give any errors, it just does nothing for those

```
# extract tree first symbols and save them in the new column
df['first_three_symbols'] = df['ITEM'].str[0:3]
#create a boolean column on condition whether first three symbols contain symbols
df["ccv"] = df["first_three_symbols"].str.contains('[ptkbdgG_fvsSxzZhmnNJlrwj][ptkbdgG_fvsSxzZhmnNJlrwj][IEAOYye|aouKLM@)3*<!(#0~q^LMOEK]')

#create another column for True values in the previous column
if df["ccv"].item == True:
    df['first_two_symbols'] = df["ITEM"].str[0:2]
```

Here is my output:

```
          ID            ITEM  FREQ first_three_symbols    ccv
0          0               a   563                   a  False
1          1       OlrMndmEn     1                 Olr  False
2          2  OlrMndSpOrtl@r     0                 Olr  False
3          3            AG@l    74                 AG@  False
4          4         AG@lbMm    24                 AG@  False
...      ...             ...   ...                 ...    ...
51723  51723         zytzWt@     8                 zyt  False
51724  51724       zytzytOst     0                 zyt  False
51725  51725          zYxtIx     5                 zYx  False
51726  51726       zYxtIxkWt     0                 zYx  False
51727  51727            zyZe     4                 zyZ  False

[51728 rows x 5 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either create a function, use apply method :

```
def f(row):
  if row["ccv"] == True:
     return row["ITEM"].str[0:2]
  else:
     return None

df['first_two_symbols'] = df.apply(f,axis=1)
```

or you can use [np.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)function from numpy package.